# Need help debugging a cron job

Tags: php, cron

I have a cron job that isn't running.  I'm not terribly experienced in this area so I may be missing something obvious but I just can't figure it out.

Here is the relevant text from crontab.  (This is running on a Windows server of some kind.  Unfortunately I don't know the details of the configuration.)

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /usr/apps/nrbadm/php_invoker framework/index.php dc rezound newsql > /dev/null 2>&1
0,15,30,45 * * * * /usr/apps/nrbadm/php_invoker framework/index.php dc droid4 newsql > /dev/null 2>&1
0,15,30,45 * * * * /usr/apps/nrbadm/php_invoker framework/index.php dc ipad3 newsql &> /tmp/crn/ipad3.log
10,25,40,55 * * * * /usr/apps/nrbadm/php_invoker2 galaxys3_data.php >> /usr/apps/webdata/dashboards/cronlog.txt
10,25,40,55 * * * * /usr/apps/nrbadm/php_invoker2 galaxys3_data_full.php >> /usr/apps/webdata/dashboards/cronlog.txt
10,25,40,55 * * * * /usr/apps/nrbadm/php_invoker2 incredible4_data.php >> /usr/apps/webdata/dashboards/cronlog.txt
0,15,30,45 * * * * /usr/apps/nrbadm/php_invoker_gen queue_summary_data.php >> /usr/apps/webdata/cron/errorlog.txt
```

That last line is the one that isn't working.  I included the other lines for comparison because those *are* working.  The first three lines call a script called php_invoker.  (If the syntax looks weird it's because this script is in a CodeIgniter environment.)  These were set up by the programmer I replaced.

The second set of 3 were set up by me.  We are porting the site out of CodeIgniter so I had to port these files.  I copied php_invoker, made php_invoker2 with the necessary edits, and it worked.  So when it came time to set up this new one I did the same thing, except it's not running.  The new script, php_invoker_gen, is designed to run any PHP script on the server in the "cron" folder.

Here is the full text of php_invoker_gen:

```
#!/bin/bash

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/apps/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/lib32:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

/usr/apps/php/bin/php -f /usr/apps/webdata/cron/$1
```

As I said this was copied from the original php_invoker script.  The only thing I changed was the second part of the last line to point to the PHP script I'm trying to run.  I don't fully understand everything that is happening here but from what I've been able to figure out (and somebody correct me if I'm wrong) the $1 is a variable that is replaced with the value that is passed in the crontab line above, so "queue_summary_data.php."

The resulting path should be:

```
/usr/apps/webdata/cron/queue_summary_data.php
```

I have verified that this path is correct.  Permissions on this file are set to 777.  (I know this is overkill but I've reached the point of trying anything.)

I have also verified that the path to the script being called is correct:

```
/usr/apps/nrbadm/php_invoker_gen
```

Permissions on that file are set to 755, so it is executable.  This is the same permission level as the other two scripts which are running.

If I log into the server via PuTTY I can run the script from the command line.

```
/usr/apps/php/bin/php -f /usr/apps/webdata/cron/queue_summary_data.php
```

That works when typed into the terminal window.  The script runs and the data is updated properly.  But the cron job just doesn't want to run.

I've run out of ideas for debugging this thing.  The fact that I did this once before without any trouble is what's really frustrating me.  I'm sure it's something simple that I have overlooked but I have no idea what it could be.

Thanks in advance for your help.

->Later.....Spice

Comment: I believe so, especially since the other cron scripts are functioning normally.  How can I check?

Comment: I would add MAILTO="email@domain.com" at the top of your crontab. That way any responses/warnings/errors will get emailed to you. And you can make sure it is at least running.

Comment: Have you tried running it from the command line exactly as it is in the cron? Run this: `/usr/apps/nrbadm/php_invoker_gen queue_summary_data.php >> /usr/apps/webdata/cron/errorlog.txt` and see if you get any output.

Comment: "This is running on a Windows server of some kind" are you sure about that? Normally cron doesn't run on windows and your file paths are setup completely wrong for windows.

Comment: No, I'm not, frankly.  I was told it was a Windows server when I started but honestly there's a lot of miscommunication around here.

Comment: _Have you tried running it from the command line exactly as it is in the cron?_
OK, I just did that and got an error but it scrolled up the screen before I could copy it.  Something about bash.  I'll try it again.

Comment: OK, the error is `: bad interpreter: No such file or directoryn/bash`.  So why would the other scripts work and not this one?

Comment: OK, I think I figured it out.  The script was copied and edited on my desktop PC then uploaded to the server, so it had the wrong carriage returns at the end.  I just fixed that.  I'll let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so the question is closed and answered it was the newline characters on the script that was causing errors when it ran.  I edited the file on the server in the terminal to delete them and it started running.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: If that's what solved your problem, you should mark this as an answer.

Comment: I've been trying to.  The site wouldn't let me for X number of hours because I'm new around here.  It says I can accept this answer in 20 hours.